# Problems setting up home web server

Tags: router, home-server

Has anyone been able to get a server working with the router `smcwbr14t-g`? Although I have been able to get Apache set up correctly and my website works on the internal IP `192.168.2.101`, I've been running into a dead end when trying to get it to show up on my external IP.

In my router, there is no option for port forwarding, but there are options for a 'virtual server'. Following the manual, I have it set up like this:

[image]

I also disabled the firewall.

I configured Apache to listen to ports 80, 81, and 443, none of which solved the problem. However, the IP's `192.168.2.101:443` and `:81` load fine. Nevertheless the website loaded only on the internal IP, and never on the external IP.

The problem is that I still cannot load the web site from my external IP, either from my computer or outside.

Comment: Could you clarify if using port 81 or 443 worked? If they did I would suspect that your ISP is blocking traffic to port 80 on customer IPs.

Comment: Okay, I clarified it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you've only forwarded port 80/TCP, which means that 81/TCP and 443/TCP won't work externally.

Do you have an ADSL modem or another router?  What are the first 2 numbers of the WAN IP address of the smcwbr14t-g?

Have you checked with your ISP to see if they block 80/TCP or other ports?

You'll find a checklist and test process [here](http://www.dyndnscommunity.com/questions/16/how-do-i-access-my-device-from-outside-my-home-network) on another forum.

Answer (score 0):

Many ISP's do block incoming HTTP and FTP requests.  I would find this to be a very likely cause.  Some will allow you to run a server for an additional monthly fee or by request (Typically so they can monitor what you're "serving").  Others strictly forbid it.  The reason that most ISP's operate this way is to limit potential liability on their end for any potentially illegal activities that you might be carrying out using that server.  It's the same reason more and more ISP's are blocking or limiting torrent traffic.